# Facebook prevent my app from opening by a link android

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

iam trying to open my app from a link 
 and i succeed in it and i can open it from the link but if iam on facebook app .. its opening it with its webview so i cant open my app by its link from facebook and thats what is in my manifist

```
 <intent-filter>
                <data
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/users"
                    android:scheme="http" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


            </intent-filter>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

Comment: Isn't that precisely what SHOULD be present for intents to be "opened from links"?

Comment: @domen yes it is but for the app to be opened from the browser url, not from other app

Comment: But then why would having it in BROWSABLE category limit this behaviour? Do you have any references and/or have you tried this?

Comment: thanks but .. it didnt work too and give me this message Activity supporting ACTION_VIEW is not set as BROWSABLE

Comment: any another solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This may fix the issue:

```
<data android:pathPattern="/.*" />
```

So the intent filter looks like:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:host="example.com" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:pathPattern="/.*" />
</intent-filter>
```

if you register your intent for http://myexample.com and you click in http://myexample.com/blah it will not work.

Comment: sorry but it didnt work too .. look if i opened it by any browser it will be directly get my app in the app pickers but if i opened it from the facebook browser its not giving me a chance to pick my app

Comment: you should asking this problem on facebook developers console then